# Onclick popup of sharethis window

Tags: javascript, sharethis

As I have embed the sharethis plugin through the below script and it popup the share window on mouse hover event. But I required to popup only on Onclick event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
stLight.options({
    publisher:"c7a25472-030e-48ce-b630-a71f99cc53d9"
});
</script>
<span class="st_sharethis_custom" displayText="Share">Share</span>
```

So could you please advice how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the `onhover` property to `false` should work for you:

```
stLight.options({
    publisher:"c7a25472-030e-48ce-b630-a71f99cc53d9",
    onhover: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*var addthis_config = {
    ui_click: true 
}*                                                                                                 ui_click
    If true, the compact menu only appears on click.